# Adding hours to repeating minutes/seconds in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sensor that collects only minute/second tags for my data. Because of that the tags repeat. For example:

```
['00:00',
 '20:00',
 '40:00',
 '00:00',
 '20:00',
 '40:00',
 '00:00',
 '20:00',
 '40:00']
```

How can I use pandas datetimes ([to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)) to add an hour each time the minute count decreases? So that I end up with something like:

```
['00:00:00',
 '00:20:00',
 '00:40:00',
 '01:00:00',
 '01:20:00',
 '01:40:00',
 '02:00:00',
 '02:20:00',
 '02:40:00']
```

Comment: you asked a question, and then answered it yourself in less than a minute? I don't understand....

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Answering own questions is part of StackOverflow... See [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or [this SO blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) in which Jeff Atwood (stack exchange cofounder) says "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) to compare the previous minutes/seconds to the current and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get the hour offsets. Then convert these hour offsets [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add them to the original values.

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['00:00', '20:00', '40:00'] * 3

s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(l), format='%M:%S')
hours = pd.to_timedelta((s.shift() > s).cumsum(), unit='h')
(s + hours).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

gives:

```
0    00:00:00
1    00:20:00
2    00:40:00
3    01:00:00
4    01:20:00
5    01:40:00
6    02:00:00
7    02:20:00
8    02:40:00
dtype: object
```